# Exporting Access query results by record to new worksheet in file

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to workout how to split the unique records of a query to new worksheets in the same excel workbook (template file).  My access query has the following fields:

Project Number,Project Name,Task Number,Project Sponsor,Full Year Budget,APR,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Full,Year Forecast.

I want to be able to have a new worksheet for each Project Number and list the relevant data, and also rename the worksheet as the Project Number...I have a complete mind block after spending hours playing around with other code for similar requests,  but cannot get anything to behave the way I need it to?

Does any one have a ideas or could point me in the right direction,  I'm not a complete novice at vba but this one has me well and truly stuck.

Many thanks :)

Hi All, thanks for the suggestions,  I've managed to cobble together the code to spilt the data and export to individual worksheets and its working ok.I now need to copy over any associated data from another query to the relevant worksheet in a "table" below the other data,  but I'm not having much luck.  Either it will copy one record to one of the worksheets or all of the records to a single worksheet irrespective.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Option Compare Database

Global iter As Integer
Sub Loop_Practice2()



 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ProjectNumber As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Worksheet_Count As Integer
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim Project_Count As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim mvalue As String
    Dim myfile As String
    Dim mynewfile As String
    Dim mynewpath As String
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sFile As String
    mypath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\"
    myfile = ("PIN Export Template.xlsx")
    mynewpath = (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\")
    mynewfile = ("PIN Export Template.xlsx - " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx")
    sFile = mypath & myfile
'    ' Use Dir to check if file exists
    If Dir(sFile) = "" Then
' if file does not exist display message
        MsgBox "Could not find the file " & sFile & " - Please ensure it is in the same location as the database."
        Exit Sub
    End If
'Open Excel
    Excel.Application.Visible = True
    Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open (sFile)
'Define Access Query to be exported
    Set ProjectNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly.[Project Number] from qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly")
    If ProjectNumber.EOF Then Exit Sub
    ProjectNumber.MoveLast
    Project_Count = ProjectNumber.RecordCount - 1
    ProjectNumber.MoveFirst
'Create individual PIN sheets from Query Dataset
    Excel.Application.Worksheets("PIN").Select
    Worksheet_Count = Excel.Application.Worksheets("PIN").Select
    Do Until Worksheet_Count = Project_Count
        Worksheets("PIN").Copy After:=Worksheets("PIN")
        If iter = 0 Then
            iter = 1
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Name = ("PIN") & iter
        iter = iter + 1
        Worksheet_Count = Worksheet_Count + 1
    Loop
    j = 1
'Add qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly data
    Do Until ProjectNumber.EOF
        sSql = "SELECT *"
        sSql = sSql & " FROM qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly"
        sSql = sSql & " Where qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly.[Project Number]=" & ProjectNumber("[Project Number]")
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenDynaset)
        Set Pin_Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PIN" & j)
'Rename the PIN sheet to individual Project Number
        Pin_Sheet.Name = ProjectNumber("[Project Number]")
'Create PIN Analysis Column Headings
        For iCol = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Pin_Sheet.Cells(13, iCol + 4).Value = rs.Fields(iCol).Name
        Next
'Populate PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly Data
        Pin_Sheet.Cells(14, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs
        j = j + 1
        ProjectNumber.MoveNext
        Loop
    Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (mynewpath & mynewfile)
    Set Pin_Sheet = Nothing
    Set ProjectNumber = Nothing
    Set ProjectNumber2 = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set ProjectNumber = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set WS = Nothing
    CurrentDb.Close

ActiveWorkbook.Close
Excel.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently, this question is too broad. Selecting only unique values, exporting the data, and renaming a worksheet are all very different tasks. Please ask about only one of them, and provide enough information to answer it (e.g. sample data, your most promising attempt).

Comment: Hi @ ErikvonAsmuth,  thanks for the update,  I understand what you're saying here, just not sure how to explain what I'm trying to do...essentially I have a query - qry_MP_PDP_PIN_Analysis_Step_01_FY_Position_Monthly.  This has a few hundred records within it,  but these are details of 5 Project Numbers.  Whilst I know how to transfer the whole dataset over to an existing worksheet,  I cant workout how to split this data by project number and export to a worksheet for each project number?  I don't have any idea how to do this...

Comment: @CBHodgetts . first of all create a query where you have different project number than loop through your recodset for different project number and use this project number for your Excel Sheet Name.

Answer (score 0):

AS **'Erik von Asmuth'** Suggested it is a broad question split into a different task and share your code. what you have attempted until now.

I can only point you to one article written by **Daniel Pineault** . He had created a function called **ExportRecordset2XLS** through which you can pass your recordset, Sheet Name etc.

you have to create a loop for different project number and pass as an argument to this function. you also need to modify this code to handle differnt task as per your requiremnts.

https://www.devhut.net/2017/03/15/ms-access-vba-export-recordset-to-excel/